# How can I make the dark black frames in the image white?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have this first image where there is a massive white background around the image and then a darker frame. I want to get rid off that extra white parts around the image as well as the dark frame. Basically I want to have the same image like in the second image down below. How can I do this, preferably using PIL library (if not OpenCv is fine)? Sorry for the editing but those are the original images that I am using. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Convert to grayscale, Otsu-threshold, get the most external contour, get its bounding box, use that info to crop the inner image.

Answer (score 3):

Following stateMachine's suggestions, here's a python implementation using opencv:

```
import cv2

filename = 'input_image.jpg'
input_image = cv2.imread(filename)
grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# use Otsu's method to determine the threshold
threshold, binary_image = cv2.threshold(grayscale_image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# contours are sorted from large to small, use the second because the first
# describes the entire image. find left, top, right and bottom coordinates of # the second contour by finding the smallest x and y values for points on the # contour, than the largest

left = contours[1][:, 0, 0].min()
top = contours[1][:, 0, 1].min()

right = contours[1][:, 0, 0].max()
bottom = contours[1][:, 0, 1].max()

# crop the target image from the input image

cropped_image = input_image[top:bottom+1, left:right+1, :]
```

Comment: Tested: it works for gülsemin's images.
Add control displays:

cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", input_image)
cv2.imshow("CROPPED", cropped_image)
print("Press a key...")
cv2.waitKey(0)

Answer (score 1):

I also came up with a solution using `point` method from PIL library if someone will need

```
n = 2
img = Image.open('input_image.jpg')
img_grey = img.convert('L')
img_binary = img_grey.point(lambda x:255 if x<=255 and x>150 else 0)
arr_binary = np.array(img_binary)
img_original_arr = np.array(img)
    
min_row = np.argwhere(arr_binary==0)[:,0].min()
max_row = np.argwhere(arr_binary==0)[:,0].max()
min_col = np.argwhere(arr_binary==0)[:,1].min()
max_col = np.argwhere(arr_binary==0)[:,1].max()
    
new_arr = arr_binary[min_row+(n-1):max_row-n, min_col+(n-1):max_col-n]
```

where `n` is an integer defines the thickness of the frame.